# How to recode a field into this specific structure using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a column (ID) in a table (tbl1). The column ID is a `nvarchar` field.

Here are some examples of what it contains:

```
   ID  
18FD64245
533040174
12AZ61356
19AK13355
18HD24189
```

I would like to run a T-SQL query to recode those values based on the following logic:

```
IF  THEN    IF  THEN
A   1       0   3
B   2       1   6
C   3       2   7
D   4       3   1
E   5       4   2
F   6       5   4
G   7       6   8
H   8       7   9
I   9       8   5
J   10      9   0
K   11          
L   12          
M   13          
N   14          
O   15          
P   16          
Q   17          
R   18          
S   19          
T   20          
U   21          
V   22          
W   23          
X   24          
Y   25          
Z   26
```

Therefore the first 2 values shown above would be recoded as:

```
   ID         ID2
18FD64245  656482724
533040174  411323692
```

I am having a hard time approaching the problem from a `T-SQL` point of view. I am thinking about using `CASE` Statements to solve the problem. I also had a look at the `REPLACE` function.
But I am stuck as to how to go about it since the ID field is an alpha-numeric field.

Any ideas on how I move forward with this?

Edit (to show my sql codes as per answer proposed by @Squirrel):

```
declare @map table
(
    map_fr  char(1),
    map_to  varchar(2)
)


insert into @map 
values 

('A', '1'),
('B', '2'),
('C', '3'),
('D', '4'),
('E', '5'),
('F', '6'),
('G', '7'),
('H', '8'),
('I', '9'),
('J', '10'),
('K', '11'),
('L', '12'),
('M', '13'),
('N', '14'),
('O', '15'),
('P', '16'),
('Q', '17'),
('R', '18'),
('S', '19'),
('T', '20'),
('U', '21'),
('V', '22'),
('W', '23'),
('X', '24'),
('Y', '25'),
('Z', '26')


; with rcte as
(
    select  [ID], idx = 1, ch = substring([ID], 1, 1)
    from   Table1

    WHERE [ID] IS NOT NULL


    union all

    select  [ID], idx = idx + 1, ch = substring([ID], idx + 1, 1)
    from    rcte
    where   idx < len([ID])

),

cte as
(
    select  r.[ID], r.idx, m.map_to
    from    rcte r
            inner join @map m   on  r.ch = m.map_fr
)


select  [ID],
        (select '' + map_to from cte x where x.[ID] = c.[ID] order by idx for xml path('')) as ID2
from    cte c
group by [ID]
order by [ID]
```

Comment: `18FD64245` to  `655382724`. Isn't the `F` suppose to be `6` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, typo error. I have corrected accordingly.

Comment: If you are planning on using this on several occasions, I'd recommend creating a scalar function for it. Also, you realize that this conversion is a one way trip, right?

Comment: @EzLo Thanks. What do you mean by a "one way trip"?

Comment: This might be a [xy-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The new codes will not allow you to re-find the old ID (e.g. "W" translates to "24" and you will not know, if "24" was a "W" or "40" in the original). If the new ID is just this, a new ID, I'd avoid any semi-magic tricks and just use a new ID. You can keep a legacy mapping table to find old IDs if needed...

Comment: Sorry, the given example was wrong.. The "W" translates to "23"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a mapping table like

```
declare @map table
(
    map_fr  char(1),
    map_to  varchar(2)
)
```

and insert the mapping there

```
insert into @map 
values  ('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4'), ('E', '5'), ('F', '6'),
        ('G', '7'), ('H', '8'), ('I', '9'), ('J', '10'),('K', '11'),('L', '12'),
        ('M', '13'),('N', '14'),('O', '15'),('P', '16'),('Q', '17'),('R', '18'),
        ('S', '19'),('T', '20'),('U', '21'),('V', '22'),('W', '23'),('X', '24'),
        ('Y', '25'),('Z', '26'),
        ('0', '3'), ('1', '6'), ('2', '7'), ('3', '1'), ('4', '2'), ('5', '4'),
        ('6', '8'), ('7', '9'), ('8', '5'), ('9', '0')
```

then use recursive CTE to split the character and join to the mapping table. And finally concatenate back the string using the mapped value.

```
; with rcte as
(
    select  ID, idx = 1, ch = substring(ID, 1, 1)
    from    yourtbl 

    union all

    select  ID, idx = idx + 1, ch = substring(ID, idx + 1, 1)
    from    rcte
    where   idx < len(ID)

),
cte as
(
    select  r.ID, r.idx, m.map_to
    from    rcte r
            inner join @map m   on  r.ch    = m.map_fr
)
select  ID,
        (select '' + map_to from cte x where x.ID = c.ID order by idx for xml path('')) as ID2
from    cte c
group by ID
order by ID
```

Comment: Thanks. However, do I not need another map table for the numerical values of 0 to 9? From your example, it seems the @map table will be mapping only the alphabets A to Z.

Comment: the same mapping table should includes all the mapping you need. A to Z and 0 to 9. You don't need a separate mapping table for 0 to 9

Comment: I am getting 64 as output for ID 18FD64245 which is not correct.
I have inserted values for A to Z (with corresponding numerical values of 1 to 26) in the @map table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the mapping table that you used and the full query. I have tested for `18FD64245` and it does gives the same result `656482724`

Comment: you didn't includes the numeric for @map, that's why it is only able to translate the 2 chracters `FD` out of `18FD64245` which gives you `64`

Comment: i have updated my answer with the complete `@map`. You may refer to that

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited as an scalar function, but if you want to do it all on a single SQL statement, here is a way :

```
select ID,
       case substring(ID, 1, 1) when 'A' then '1'
                                when 'B' then '2'
                                ...
                                when '9' then '0'
       end
       +  
       case substring(ID, 2, 1) when 'A' then '1'
                                when 'B' then '2'
                                ...
                                when '9' then '0'
       end
       +
       ...
       ...
       case substring(ID, 9, 1) when 'A' then '1'
                                when 'B' then '2'
                                ...
                                when '9' then '0'
       end
       as ID2
from MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives me a NULL as output (ID2) for each ID value.

Comment: @user3115933, yes your IDs have 9 characters, not 10 characters as I have posted initially.

Answer (score -1):

You can also map these using a tally table and some of the new features of SQL Server 2017 (`STRING_AGG`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1d8fd1/49)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IDS
(
  ID NVARCHAR(9)
 )
 INSERT INTO IDS
 VALUES ('18FD64245'),
        ('533040174'),
        ('12AZ61356'),
        ('19AK13355'),
        ('18HD24189');
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Tally
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Nums.Num) AS Number
  FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS Nums(Num)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS Nums2(Num)
 ),
 Chars
 As
 (
   -- Turn each character of ID to new row
    SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(ID, Number, 1) AS OldChar, Number As Ind
    FROM IDS
    CROSS APPLY Tally
    WHERE SUBSTRING(ID, Number, 1) <> ''

  ),
  NewChars
  AS
  (
    -- Map old characters to new characters
    SELECT *, 
          CASE WHEN ISNumeric(OldChar) = 1 THEN
            -- effectively a mapping string to map old characters to new
            SUBSTRING('3671248950', CHARINDEX(OldChar, '0123456789'), 1)
           ELSE
             -- for alphanumeric we can simply make 'A' be 1 and 'B' be 2
             -- by subtracting the ASCII value of 'A' from the ASCII of the
             -- Character and add 1
              ASCII(OldChar) - ASCII('A') + 1
         END As NewChar
    FROM Chars
  )
  -- Recombine New Characters to form new Id (SQL Server 2017 only)
  SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(NewChar,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Ind) AS NewId
  FROM NewChars
  GROUP BY ID
  ORDER BY Id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1d8fd1/49/0)**:

```
|        ID |      NewId |
|-----------|------------|
| 12AZ61356 | 6712686148 |
| 18FD64245 |  656482724 |
| 18HD24189 |  658472650 |
| 19AK13355 | 6011161144 |
| 533040174 |  411323692 |
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, this answers the question and is a complete workable sample with explanations.